# How to change data in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a DataTable (https://datatables.net) and I want to do a few things and they all kinda have to do with refreshing the table itself. Here is my code:

```
let statusList = getStatusList();

function getRes(callback) { // ADDED CALLBACK
let city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'reservations2.php?city='+city,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: callback  // USED CALLBACK
    });
}

getRes(function (result) { // APPLIED CALLBACK
  $('#resdatatable').dataTable({
     data: result,             // YOUR RESULT
      columns: [
        { data: 'id', title: 'ID' },
        { data: 'bookingdatetime', title: 'Booking Date' },
        { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { data: 'class', title: 'Class' },
        { data: 'pickupdatetime', title: 'Pick up' },
        { data: 'duration', title: 'Duration' },
        { data: 'dropdatetime', title: 'Drop off' },
        { data: 'age', title: 'Age' },
        { data: 'coverage', title: 'Coverage' },
        { data: 'quote', title: 'Quote' },
        {
          data: 'status',
          title: 'Status',
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            let isKnown = statusList.filter(function(k) { return k.id === data; }).length > 0;
            if (isKnown) {
              return $('<select id ="resstatus'  + row.id + '" onchange="changeResStatus(' + row.id + ')">', {
                id: 'resstatus-' + row.id, // custom id
                value: data
              }).append(statusList.map(function(knownStatus) {
                let $option = $('<option>', {
                  text: knownStatus.text,
                  value: knownStatus.id
                });
                if (row.status === knownStatus.id) {
                  $option.attr('selected', 'selected')
                }
                return $option;
              })).on('change', function() {
                changeresstatus(row.id); // Call change with row ID
              }).prop('outerHTML');
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
});

/**
 * jQuery plugin to convert text in a cell to a dropdown
 */
(function($) {
  $.fn.createDropDown = function(items) {
    let oldTxt = this.text();
    let isKnown = items.filter(function(k) { return k.id === oldTxt; }).length > 0;
    if (isKnown) {
      this.empty().append($('<select>').append(items.map(function(item) {
        let $option = $('<option>', {
          text: item.text,
          value: item.id
        });
        if (item.id === oldTxt) {
          $option.attr('selected', 'selected')
        }
        return $option;
      })));
    }
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

// If you remove the renderer above and change this to true,
// you can call this, but it will run once...
if (false) {
  $('#resdatatable > tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).find('td').last().createDropDown(statusList);
  });
}


function getStatusList() {
  return [{
    id: 'Confirmed',
    text: 'Confirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Unconfirmed',
    text: 'Unconfirmed'
  }, {
    id: 'Open',
    text: 'Open'
  }, {
    id: 'Closed',
    text: 'Closed'
  }, {
    id: 'Canceled',
    text: 'Canceled'
  }];
}

function changeResStatus(str1) {
    var id = str1;
    var status = document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value;
    var mailres = "";

    var r = confirm("Change Status for ID # " + id + " to " + status + "?");
    if (r == true) {

        if (document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value == "Confirmed"){
            var s = confirm("Send ID # " + id + " a confirmation email?");
            if (s == true) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","sendconfirmationemail.php?id="+id,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","changeresstatus.php?id="+id+"&status="+status,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<div class='errormessage'>Change status action aborted</div>";
        getrestable();
    }
    }
```

As you can see my DataTable renders on page load. I want the DataTable to update when the `cityselect` is changed, right now I have:

```
<select id="cityselect" onchange="getRes()">
```

But that does not work. How can I make that work?

EDIT: I have changed the question to ask only one question.

Comment: Move your `let city=` into the function that you use it within.  As it is, it's only set once when the page loads.

Comment: I am pretty lost then, I would love more of an explanation though! This is my first time using DataTables

Comment: Your select also has `onchange=getResult` but you've not included `getResult` in your code.  (while including tons of irrelevant browser-specific ajax code which just confuses the question).   Could it be that simple that you don't have a matching `onchange` event?

Comment: Ok, you've *changed your question* (without comment) to match the two possible issues mentioned above.  Your onchange now calls a function that expects a callback, without the callback - so still won't work.  **Please provide the actual code that you're using.** (and don't change it based on comments, because then it's not the code that you're using)

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the changes, no that's not the issue.

Comment: "*does not work.*" is too vague - you'll need to be more specific.  Browser console error? network tab error? event not firing?

Comment: The answers below me provided a an error, commented on below.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this line of code

```
 $('#Datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Getting this popup error: DataTables warning: table id=resdatatable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'g.data=f')

Comment: Yes. I changed the name of the element to reflect mine.